# Find a vector $x\in\Bbb R^2$ s. t. $T(x)=b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, operator-theory

> Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-3\\3&5\\    -1&7\\\end{bmatrix},b=\begin{bmatrix}    3\\2\\-5\\\end{bmatrix},c=\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\5\\\end{bmatrix}, u =\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\\end{bmatrix}$$ and define a linear transformation of $$T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3\ \ \ T(x):= Ax$$
>
> **(a)** Find $T(u)$
>
> **(b)** Find $a,b\in\Bbb R^2$ s.t. $T(a)=T(b)=b$.
>
> **(c)** Is there more than one $x$ s.t. $T(x)=b$?
>
> **(d)** Determine whether $c\in\operatorname{Im}T$

This question is very frustrating, stressful, and annoying, and I have spent literally $8\mathrm{h}$ trying to solve it, looking up stuff on the internet, as there is NOTHING like it in the note books. All of what we have is $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ with predefined "defined by" values. Asking the professor, he says to "Look it up.", which isn't helpful.

What I know that I have to do is:
$T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$

and

$T(cx) = cT(x)$

I don't know where to go from there...

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't put the matrices in the title.  It takes up too much space in the list of questions.

Comment: Yeah, I was editing it, but you did it first. Thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso, how could you possibly find the inverse of a non-isomorphic operator (because it isn't even surjective), and whose matrix representation isn't even a square matrix? Don't confuse people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know how to multiply a matrix and a vector, so find $Au$ and that is $T(u)$

For the other parts you need to find a vector $v$ such that $Av$ is given.

So you solve for the components of $v$ and see if the answer is unique or even if you have an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user225589 Thanks  for  attention.